# ThreadPoolExecutor timeout configuration

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I want to setup a timeout for my ThreadPoolExecutor.

I know that i can use

```
future.get(THREAD_TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

But this code is blocking.

What i want to achieve is that i can create several Runables which are processed with a pool of 4 threads for example.

If the processing of the thread takes more than e.g. 5 seconds i want to throw a timeout exception.

This is my current setup:

```
public class ServerExecutorService {

    public static int QUEUE_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_SECONDS = 5;
    public static int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 12;
    public static int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 12;
    public static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerExecutorService .class);
    public static int THREAD_TIMEOUT_MS = 5000;
    private LinkedBlockingQueue linkedBlockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue(2);
    private RejectedHandler rejectedHandler = new RejectedHandler();


    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, QUEUE_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS, linkedBlockingQueue);

    public ServerExecutorService () {
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(this.rejectedHandler);
    }

    public void setRejectedHandler(RejectedHandler rejectedHandler) {
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(rejectedHandler);
    }


    public void execute(Runnable runnable){
//        executor.execute(runnable);
//        Future<?> future = executor.submit(runnable);
        Future<?> future = executor.submit(runnable);

        try {
            future.get(THREAD_TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread processing timeout.");
            LOG.warn("Thread processing timeout.", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Thread processing error within ServerExecutorService ");
            LOG.error("Thread processing error within ServerExecutorService ", e);
        }
    }

}
```

But like you can see the future.get(THREAD_TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); will wait until the Thread has finished. So the next Threads are not started.

Test:

```
@Test
    public void testThreadPoolExhausted() {
        serverExecutorService.setRejectedHandler(rejectedHandler);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            final int finalI = i;
            serverExecutorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("do something" + finalI);
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

In this test the second thread is started after 3 seconds and not immediatly.

Comment: Ofcourse this is expected because the ServerExecutorService is blocked at future.get() method that in turn depends on the return status of the associated thread. Do you want the second thread to start immediately ?

Comment: Yes. This is what i want.

Comment: You'd better cancel your task after timeout.

Comment: I can only cancel if the timeout is reached. But how to set the timeout?

Answer (score 1):

You could create two threadpools, one for timeouts and one for the actual work.

```
ExecutorService timeoutService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
ExecutorService workerService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public Future<?> submit(final Runnable runnable){
    return timeoutService.submit(() -> {
        try {
            Future<?> future = workerService.submit(runnable);
            future.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
}
```